# Custom picture placement in exam style

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, exam

How can I put my image next to the text in the exam style? I want it to look like the second example. I am using tikz to draw the picture. The code is really long so I won't post it all here but this is the basic structure:

```
\question[3]
$\Delta$ABC~ and ~$\Delta$DAC~ are equilateral triangles.\\    
Prove that ~ABCD~ is a parallelogram, giving reasons.\droppoints    
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      some code...
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

What it looks like now:
[image]
What I want it to look like:
[image]

Comment: You don't need to post the *whole* code here, just the preamble covering the necessary packages and the class to run that part of the code, with of course, `\begin` and `\end{document}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us to help you by providing a small complete LaTeX document that shows your problem, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. Remove redundant and irrelevant stuff. You can also replace your complicated pictures by something like `\tikz\draw (0,0) rectangle (4,1);`; make it approximately the size of your pictures. Use the [edit button](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/332848/edit) left below your posting to add the code.

Comment: General remark without knowing the details of your code: If you put the picture in a `center` environment, you tell LaTeX to put it below the text. To have it side by side, you have to put your text into some box (`minipage` environment, `\parbox` etc) and put text, picture (without `center` environment) and `\droppoints` immediately below/beside each other, without intervening blank line (= start of paragraph), only separated by space commands like `\quad`, `\hfill` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way (I think), is to use minipages (adjust the sizes to your needs).
Maybe use [t] [b] or [c] to position them vertically.

```
\begin{minipage}{10cm}
  question[3]
  $\Delta$ABC~ and ~$\Delta$DAC~ are equilateral triangles.\\ 
  Prove that ~ABCD~ is a parallelogram, giving reasons.\droppoints 
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{4cm}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      some code...
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of your images, `multicol` sometimes serves the purpose.

```
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\pointsdroppedatright

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}

\question[3]
\begin{multicols}{2}
    $\Delta$ABC~ and ~$\Delta$DAC~ are equilateral triangles. 
    Prove that ~ABCD~ is a parallelogram, giving reasons.%\droppoints    

\columnbreak

    \includegraphics[height=1in]{gram}    \droppoints

\end{multicols}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This has been the best work-around and one can change the \put values to move the image exactly into place.

```
 \begin{picture}(50,50)
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \put(200,20){\hbox{   
     %some code...
  }}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{picture}
```